# follow hard links (reparsepoints?) to files (windows terminal)?

Tags: powershell, uwp, reparsepoint

How do you follow a hard link (reparse point?) to a file?  Piping to format-list doesn't show the target.  At least in powershell 7, you get a little ascii arrow.  That folder is in the $env:path.  MicrosoftEdge.exe is linked in the same folder, if you don't have Windows Terminal.  I'm in win10 20h2.

```
get-item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe

    Directory: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
la---           3/31/2022  1:27 PM              0 wt.exe ->


get-item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe | % attributes

Archive, ReparsePoint
```

This just gives a lot of binary:

```
fsutil reparsepoint query $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe

Reparse Tag Value : 0x8000001b
Tag value: Microsoft

Reparse Data Length: 0x192
Reparse Data:
0000:  03 00 00 00 4d 00 69 00  63 00 72 00 6f 00 73 00  ....M.i.c.r.o.s.
0010:  6f 00 66 00 74 00 2e 00  57 00 69 00 6e 00 64 00  o.f.t...W.i.n.d.
0020:  6f 00 77 00 73 00 54 00  65 00 72 00 6d 00 69 00  o.w.s.T.e.r.m.i.
0030:  6e 00 61 00 6c 00 50 00  72 00 65 00 76 00 69 00  n.a.l.P.r.e.v.i.
0040:  65 00 77 00 5f 00 38 00  77 00 65 00 6b 00 79 00  e.w._.8.w.e.k.y.
0050:  62 00 33 00 64 00 38 00  62 00 62 00 77 00 65 00  b.3.d.8.b.b.w.e.
0060:  00 00 4d 00 69 00 63 00  72 00 6f 00 73 00 6f 00  ..M.i.c.r.o.s.o.
0070:  66 00 74 00 2e 00 57 00  69 00 6e 00 64 00 6f 00  f.t...W.i.n.d.o.
0080:  77 00 73 00 54 00 65 00  72 00 6d 00 69 00 6e 00  w.s.T.e.r.m.i.n.
0090:  61 00 6c 00 50 00 72 00  65 00 76 00 69 00 65 00  a.l.P.r.e.v.i.e.
00a0:  77 00 5f 00 38 00 77 00  65 00 6b 00 79 00 62 00  w._.8.w.e.k.y.b.
00b0:  33 00 64 00 38 00 62 00  62 00 77 00 65 00 21 00  3.d.8.b.b.w.e.!.
00c0:  41 00 70 00 70 00 00 00  43 00 3a 00 5c 00 50 00  A.p.p...C.:.\.P.
00d0:  72 00 6f 00 67 00 72 00  61 00 6d 00 20 00 46 00  r.o.g.r.a.m. .F.
00e0:  69 00 6c 00 65 00 73 00  5c 00 57 00 69 00 6e 00  i.l.e.s.\.W.i.n.
00f0:  64 00 6f 00 77 00 73 00  41 00 70 00 70 00 73 00  d.o.w.s.A.p.p.s.
0100:  5c 00 4d 00 69 00 63 00  72 00 6f 00 73 00 6f 00  \.M.i.c.r.o.s.o.
0110:  66 00 74 00 2e 00 57 00  69 00 6e 00 64 00 6f 00  f.t...W.i.n.d.o.
0120:  77 00 73 00 54 00 65 00  72 00 6d 00 69 00 6e 00  w.s.T.e.r.m.i.n.
0130:  61 00 6c 00 50 00 72 00  65 00 76 00 69 00 65 00  a.l.P.r.e.v.i.e.
0140:  77 00 5f 00 31 00 2e 00  38 00 2e 00 31 00 30 00  w._.1...8...1.0.
0150:  39 00 32 00 2e 00 30 00  5f 00 78 00 36 00 34 00  9.2...0._.x.6.4.
0160:  5f 00 5f 00 38 00 77 00  65 00 6b 00 79 00 62 00  _._.8.w.e.k.y.b.
0170:  33 00 64 00 38 00 62 00  62 00 77 00 65 00 5c 00  3.d.8.b.b.w.e.\.
0180:  77 00 74 00 2e 00 65 00  78 00 65 00 00 00 30 00  w.t...e.x.e...0.
0190:  00 00                                             ..
```

Even Sysinternals Findlinks doesn't work:

```
findlinks $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe

Findlinks v1.1 - Locate file hard links
Copyright (C) 2011-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error opening c:\users\js2010\appdata\local\microsoft\windowsapps\wt.exe:
The file cannot be accessed by the system.
```

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be a special kind of hard link. [FindLinks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/findlinks) also can't resolve the link. Neither does [this .NET code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572672/7571258).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65583702/7571258) shows a way, but PS 7.2.2 didn't output anything for me.

Comment: `(Get-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe).Target` in `pwsh.exe` (PSVersion `7.1.5`)

Comment: @JosefZ I'm in 7.2.2 and there's no target property.

Comment: @zett42 There's not even a LinkType property anymore.

Comment: https://github.com/googleprojectzero/sandbox-attacksurface-analysis-tools provides a `Get-ExecutionAlias` command that works. I can make that an answer if you like. It would be nice if we could isolate only the necessary code though.

Comment: More info: https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2019/09/overview-of-windows-execution-aliases.html

Comment: *How do you follow a hard link (reparse point?) to a file?*  `Start-Process -FilePath $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe` should work…

Comment: @mklement0 This just confirms what I already thought, that uwp apps are the enemy of administrators.

Comment: I agree that it's an obscure feature, but in what way are administrators affected, specifically (I'm asking innocently)?

Comment: @mklement0 So there's untraceable links in the path?  To me that's a security risk in itself.

Comment: It's obscure, but from what I can tell no more a security risk than tampering with or replacing a stand-alone executable.

Comment: @zett42, it's actually not a hard link, and, while link-like, not even a link as such (the   name-surrogate flag isn't set in the reparse point). Instead, it is an AppX reparse point aka app execution alias, associated with UWP / Microsoft Store applications - see my answer.

Comment: @mklement0 I appreciate the work you've done.  With this badly engineered system, maybe there isn't a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for responding. There is a good answer _to your question_, which I believe I have given: it lays out the reality of the situation, in detail. That you _don't like that there's no good solution to what you intended to do_ is an entirely separate matter, and should have no bearing on which answer you accept. In short: If the answer to "How can I do X?" is truly "You cannot / can only somewhat / aren't supposed to do X",
the question is still answered. That what you intended to do cannot be done isn't a shortcoming of the answer.

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr**

- `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe` is an ***AppX reparse point*** aka ***app execution alias*** aka (internally) `AppExecLink`, a Microsoft-specific [NTFS reparse point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/reparse-points), used with **[UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) / Microsoft Store** applications as entry points, i.e. the executables that launch them.

  - *Hard links* are unrelated, both conceptually and technically.
- **While such a reparse point's data does point to another file** - similar to a *symbolic link* - **the data is considered an *undocumented implementation detail* by Microsoft, subject to change**.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Therefore, **while you technically *can* parse that data, you shouldn't**, or at least you shouldn't rely on it in production code, as there is no guarantee of long-term stability.
  - **Such reparse points can be executed like any other executable, which is usually sufficient**.
  - **While you may want to know which *different* executable is ultimately launched *behind the scenes*, *static* analysis of the reparse data isn't *guaranteed* to give you that information**, as in some cases a *generic launcher executable* is used, which opaquely launches the ultimate target executable (see below for details). In other words: the target executable stored in the reparse data isn't necessarily the real target executable.
  - **Resolving an AppX reparse point to its target executable is deeply embedded in the system**, namely in the [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) family of WinAPI functions. **You need *runtime* analysis** to see what executable a given launched AppX reparse point ends up invoking; a simple way to is to invoke interactively and look for the resulting process in Task Manager; [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/16295#discussion_r736028929) shows a complex programmatic approach based on the [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamew) WinAPI function

---

> How do you follow a hard link (reparse point?) to a file?

**A *hard link* is *not* a *reparse point*.**

Hard links, in fact, do not point to *other file paths*, the way that *symbolic* links do, for instance.

Instead, **a group of related hard links directly point to the same file *data*, without any relationship between their *paths***.

However, unlike on Unix-like platforms, the system APIs on Windows allow you to directly discover all paths pointing to the same file data, given *one* of those paths.

In *Windows PowerShell*, this array of related paths is exposed via the `.Target` property that `System.IO.FileInfo` instances emitted by `Get-ChildItem` / `Get-Item` are decorated with.

Unfortunately, this was *removed* in PowerShell (Core) v6+ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61195149/45375) for details.

---

By contrast, ***other* forms of NTFS links - notably *symbolic links* (symlinks), but also the older  *junctions* and *volume mount point* types - *are* [reparse points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/reparse-points)**. I'll refer to them collectively as *symlinks* below.

*Reparse points* are essentially just *metadata* attached to a file-system entry, and their use is *open-ended*; for instance, reparse points are also used to manage on-demand downloads of cloud-hosted OneDrive files.

In short: **Symlinks are just *one* type of reparse point, and not every reparse point is a *link*.**

The subclass of reparse points that publicly point to other file-system paths are known as *name surrogates*.

---

`$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe` is an example of yet another kind of reparse point: an ***AppX reparse point*** aka ***app execution alias*** aka (internally) `AppExecLink`.

These are used by [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) applications, which notably includes all applications downloaded from the **Microsoft Store**.

While they are ***conceptually similar* to symlinks**, there are **important differences**:

- The link target isn't necessarily the true target executable; it may just be the generic UWP launcher, `C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemUWPLauncher.exe`, such as in the case of Microsoft Edge.
- More importantly, though, **Microsoft considers the reparse data associated with app execution aliases (AppX reparse points) to be an *undocumented implementation detail*, subject to change**.<sup>[1]</sup> In other words:

  - **You should treat an app execution alias just like any other (regular, self-contained) executable and *not* as a *link to another executable*.**
  - You shouldn't try to parse the reparse data yourself.

Of course, you *can* try to parse it yourself, but you cannot rely on the data format not to change.

- Note: Even when parsed correctly, the data doesn't tell you the full story, such as in the case of Microsoft Edge: the path of the executable that is ultimately used - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`, presumably launched by `C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemUWPLauncher.exe` - cannot be gleaned from the reparse data (alone).<sup>[2]</sup>

In fact, PowerShell (Core) *briefly* implemented its own parsing, but [removed it again later after internal feedback](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/16044).

The since-removed code can be found [here](https://github.com/SteveL-MSFT/PowerShell/blob/a6a66e56fb8ee864a04e3b4e08b56a9b3254619d/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/FileSystemProvider.cs#L8205), which involves P/Invoke operations and is therefore not directly available in PowerShell (though you could try ad hoc-compilation of embedded C# code via [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type)).

As [JosefZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71711350/45375) shows, you can also glean the raw byte data from the output from `fsutil reparsepoint query`, but that is both less robust and slow.

Here's an alternative implementation - slightly more robust, but still slow; once defined, invoke it as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -File $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps | Resolve-AppXExePath
```

```
function Resolve-AppXExePath {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
  Resolves AppX execution aliases to their app IDs and target paths.
.EXAMPLE
  Get-ChildItem -File $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps | Resolve-AppXExePath
 .NOTES
  This command is slow, because a call to fsutil.exe is made for each input path.
  #>
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [string] $LiteralPath
  )
  
  process {
    $fullName = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath
    if (-not $?) { return }
  
    # Get a hex-dump representation of the reparse-point data via fsutil reparsepoint query $fullName
    $hexDump = fsutil reparsepoint query $fullName 2>&1
    if ($LASTEXITCODE) { Write-Error $hexDump; return }
  
    # Extract the raw bytes that make up the reparse-point data.
    [byte[]] $bytes = -split (-join ($hexDump -match '^[a-f0-9]+:' -replace '^[a-f0-9]+:\s+(((?:[a-f0-9]{2}) +){1,16}).+$', '$1')) -replace '^', '0x'
    
    # Convert the data to a UTF-16 string and split into fields by NUL bytes.
    $props = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes) -split "`0"
    
    # Output a custom object with the App ID (Package ID + entry-point name)
    # and the target path (which may just be the universal UWP launcher)
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      AppId = $props[2]
      Target = $props[3]
    }
  
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
AppId                                                               Target
-----                                                               ------
Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App                       C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_5.721.12013.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\GameBarElevatedFT.exe
Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge                 C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemUWPLauncher.exe
Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe!PythonRedirector        C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.17.10271.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppInstallerPythonRedirector.exe
Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe!PythonRedirector        C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.17.10271.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppInstallerPythonRedirector.exe
CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc!ubuntuonwindows C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2022.1.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\ubuntu.exe
CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc!ubuntu1804 C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2020.824.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\ubuntu1804.exe
Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe!winget                  C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.17.10271.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\winget.exe
Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App                         C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.11.3471.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe
```

---

<sup>[1] See [this comment by the .NET team on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/58233#issuecomment-911971904).</sup>

[2] Whether the generic `SystemUWPLauncher.exe` launcher is used *may* be related to whether a given application is a bona fide UWP application vs. a repackaged desktop application, via the [Desktop Bridge](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/desktop-bridge-8211-the-bridge-between-desktop-apps-and-the/ba-p/316488). It is unclear to me how, when `SystemUWPLauncher.exe` is used, the ultimate target executable is determined.

Answer (score 1):

Simply parse the `fsutil.exe` output (see the `ParseFsutil` function below). Tested  under Microsoft Windows `[Version 10.0.19043.1620]`:

- `pwsh.exe` (PSVersion `7.1.5`),
- `powershell.exe`/`powershell_ise.exe` (PSVersion `5.1.19041.1620`),
- user account type: *administrator* as well as *standard user*.

Please note ugly hard-coded index (`$fsuColon`) and width (`$fsuWidth`) in `fsutil` output, and non-optimized `ParseFsutil` function…

```
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject],[System.Object[]])]
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]$Path = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\*"
)

Function ParseFsutil {
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$FullName
    )
    $fsusep = [char[]]@([char]0x20,[char]0xA0,"`t","`r","`n")
    $fsuopt = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
    $fsuexe = fsutil.exe reparsepoint query $FullName
    $fsuColon = 4             #  ugly hard-coded index in `fsutil` output
    $fsuWidth = 50            #  ugly hard-coded width in `fsutil` output
    $fsuarr = $fsuexe | 
        Where-Object { $_.Length -gt $fsuColon -and $_[$fsuColon] -eq ':' } |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.Substring($fsuColon+1, $fsuWidth).Trim().Split($fsusep, $fsuopt)
        }
    $fsuapp = [System.Text.UTF32Encoding]::Unicode.GetString(
        [byte[]]$fsuarr.ForEach({[System.Convert]::ToByte($_,16)}))
    $fsupes = [char[]](0..0x1F | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ })      # Controls
    $fsuapp.Split( $fsupes, $fsuopt )
}


Write-Verbose "PowerShell $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString())"
$RePAttr = [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint.value__
Get-ChildItem $Path -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    ForEach-Object {
        $RePoint = [psCustomObject]@{
            Name   = $_.Name;
            Source = 'Target'
            Target = ''
        }
        if (($_.Attributes.value__ -band $RePAttr) -eq $RePAttr) {
            $RePoint.Target = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Target
            if ( $null -eq $RePoint.Target -or
                 $RePoint.Target.GetType().Name -ne 'String' -or
                 $RePoint.Target.Length -lt $RePoint.Name.Length )
            {
                Write-Verbose "Target from fsutil.exe for $($RePoint.Name)"
                $RePoint.Source = 'fsutil'
                $RePoint.Target = ($_ | ParseFsutil)[2]
            }
        } else {
            Write-Verbose "Item is not a reparse point: $($RePoint.Name)"
            $RePoint.Source = 'self'
            $RePoint.Target = $_.FullName
        }
        $RePoint
    }
```

**Output** (truncated): `pwsh -nopro -file D:\PShell\SO\71697488.ps1 -Verbose`

```
VERBOSE: PowerShell 7.1.5

Name              Source Target
----              ------ ------
MicrosoftEdge.exe Target C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemUWPLauncher.exe
…
wt.exe            Target C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.12.10393.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe
```

**Output** (truncated): `powershell -nopro -file D:\PShell\SO\71697488.ps1 -Verbose`

```
VERBOSE: PowerShell 5.1.19041.1620
VERBOSE: Target from fsutil.exe for MicrosoftEdge.exe
…
VERBOSE: Target from fsutil.exe for wt.exe
Name              Source Target
----              ------ ------
MicrosoftEdge.exe fsutil C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemUWPLauncher.exe
…
wt.exe            fsutil C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.12.10393.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe
```

**Output**: `powershell -nopro -file D:\PShell\SO\71697488.ps1 -Path D:\PShell\SO\71697488.ps1 -Verbose`

```
VERBOSE: PowerShell 5.1.19041.1620
VERBOSE: Item is not a reparse point: 71697488.ps1

Name         Source Target
----         ------ ------
71697488.ps1 self   D:\PShell\SO\71697488.ps1
```

**Raw output from the `ParseFsutil` function**:

```
Get-Item "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" | ParseFsutil
```

> ```
> Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe
> Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.12.10393.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe
> 0
> ```

```
Get-Item "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftEdge.exe" |
    ParseFsutil
```

> ```
> Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
> Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemUWPLauncher.exe
> 1
> ```